# Virtual Directory, remote host with authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

is it possible to have virtual link that linked to remote host with authentication and content of my virtual folder being dynamically ?

for example , if there is file on other host :

> http://user:pass@link.com/file.text

is it possible to have this link in my host

> http://mydomain.com/file.text

all files are dynamically , and if possible not copy them in my host , jut virtual link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [redirection](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/two-approaches-to-redirection-in-aspnet/743).  And use Server.Transfer if you want to hide the URL of the remote host.

Comment: good but my Goal need some more work to do ! how about if requested link is not predefined and is folder in folder !! http://domain.com/a/b/c.txt !!!!

Comment: You could have all requests that go to http://mydomain.com/someRedirectPath/[pathToFile] get redirected to http://user:pass@link.com/[pathToFile].